# How Do I Read in a Single Character from a String?

Tags: c++

I have the line `"5 21 +"`.

I can successfully read in the 2 integers, but then I want to read in the "+" as a string.

I tried using `getLine()`, but the `getLine()` function reads in the whole line (`5 21 +`). How do I just read in the `"+"` as a string?

Comment: You can read a string value just like you read an int, using operator `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
int number1;
int number2;
std::string opr;
cin >> number1 >> number2 >> opr;
```

To get to the beginning of the next line, you could add:

```
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you want correctly.

```
string x = something.substr(5, 1); // = "+"
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to read it in as a character, and then typecast it to a string, although this is not standard procedure, and I don't recommend it. But, if you want to get the job done, it is a fast an easy way:

```
  int number 1;
  int number 2;
  char ch;
  string opr;
  cin >> number1 >> number2 >> ch;
  opr = "" + ch;
```